# Benefits of Mapping Json to Pojo?

Tags: java, json, rest, pojo

I have a rest endpoint(A) that returns a large json object. I have to return it to another rest api(B) in a different format.  Would it be beneficial to map it to an object, transform the data into the object the other REST API(B) is expecting?

Would it be better to use a json library and pull out the parts I need and transform the data that way?

Thanks

Comment: A Pojo is still better than `object.getJSONArray().getJSONObject().get...` isn't it?

Comment: Go for Jackson library by square that will take care of all parsing and will inflate your POJO directly

Comment: @MuratK. It is.  I'm just wonder if there was a better way to deal with the response.  It's a lot of data and I'm trying to optimize.

Comment: @cammando I'll use jackson if I'm mapping...which I'm currently doing unless I get a better option.

Comment: I prefer to use POJOs in my java code and transmissions are donw with JSON. My projects are configured so that a JSON object is passed in and converted with GSON to the POJO in question. Then during the response GSON automatically converts the POJO to JSON.

Comment: A and B are both JSON but structured differently? How large is A? Will the code be run simultaneously for different requests? More information is needed in order to evaluate the pros and cons of either option. Btw, we are talking about making two HTTP calls or are you going to supply an implementation of B yourself?

Comment: @MarkusBenko Json from A can be large, up to 1,000-80,000 objects coming back(One level deep flat json of about 44 attributes). There will be many multiple users hitting the same endpoint.  I'm getting the data in one HTTP call and massaging the data to fulfill a contract another api is making(they are expecting a certain data structure).  :)

Comment: Which web framework are you using? Do any restrictions apply? I'd suggest not to parse one big input JSON to POJOs and then vice versa. Instead I'd try using Jackson Streaming API and do the parse-map-generate-cycle on an per-object (= one of 80,000) basis. That way only very few memory is used per client and you won't run into trouble because of too high memory usage.

Answer (score 0):

I use Spring for my web apps. in my context config, I have:

```
<bean id="jacksonMessageConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter"></bean>
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="messageConverters">
        <list>
            <ref bean="jacksonMessageConverter"/>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Then in my controller code, I use:

```
@RequestMapping(...)
public @ResponseBody MyPojo getMyPojo(@PathVariable("id") Integer id, @RequestBody MyOtherPojo) {
    MyPojo myPojo = new MyPojo();
    // do some business methods
    return myPojo
}
```

The @ResponseBody MyPojo tells the jacksonMessageConverter to convert the MyPojo to a JSON object, and the @RequestBody tells the jacksonMessageConverter to convert a JSON variable into an instance of MyOtherPojo.

Comment: This is "how". OP wants "why?".